# Xmgrace GUI no display?

Tags: ubuntu

My goal: To use Xmgrace plotting tool for .xvg files
I tried installing on Ubuntu by the command: sudo apt-get install grace
It was successfully installed. Then when I type Xmgrace, following error message shows up:
Can't open display
Failed Initializing GUI, exiting.

Any insight would be appreciated to help this make work. It will save so much of my time instead of plotting on excel.

Many thanks,
Neena